# How to move grand summary in line with a variable column?

Tags: r, gt

I'm using the `gt` package and I would like to put grand summary names in line with a column of variables. The following example shows what I'm trying to do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(names = c("x", "y"),
             a = c(1, 2),
             b = c(3, 4))

tbl <- df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = where(is.numeric),
    fns = list(Total = ~sum(.)),
    formatter = fmt_integer
  )

tbl
```

I want "Total" to go in the names column, as drawn here:

[image: table output]

How can I do that using `gt` only?

Answer (score 3):

Is not the best solution, but here is a way to kind do that:

```
  df %>% 
  janitor::adorn_totals() %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I am trying to avoid attaching another library. Will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using `dplyr`, you may chose the perform the manipulation with it and use `gt` to display the table.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

bind_rows(df, 
df %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) %>%
  mutate(names = 'Total')) %>%
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- this is a creative solution. As specified in the revised question, however, I'm trying to do this using `gt` functions only. The actual use case involves calls to the `tab_spanner` and `cols_label` functions for columns a and b, so I can't just invoke the underlying data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use only `gt()` a possibility is to use the variable `names` as a group:

```
df %>% 
  gt(groupname_col = "names")  %>% 
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = where(is.numeric),
    fns = list(Total = ~sum(.))
  )
```

[image]

*`formatter = fmt_integer` gave me an error, so I removed

Comment: Thanks, but this is not ideal, since now x and y are on different rows from their values. (My actual use case has many more rows, so this layout would be quite unwieldy.)

Comment: I see, unfortunately was the only solution that I could thought. Let's see if someone will come with a solution